# Circle does not move right or down following arrow keypress

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my code to do the following:

1. when the right arrow key is pressed, move the circle to the right
2. when the down arrow key is pressed, move the circle to the bottom

But instead it does the following:

When one of these keys is pressed, it moves only once and than no more. What am I doing wrong?

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  var circle = document.getElementById("circle");

  if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    circle.style.left += 100;
    console.log("right")
  } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    circle.style.top += 100;
    console.log("bottom")
  }
}
```

```css
#circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Comment: You need to convert the `...style.left` and `....style.top` to floats/numbers without unit, add the value you want it to move, convert it back to `px` again and assign that value to the `.style.` Basically, those style properties are strings that need to be converted to numeric values first.... A drag, I know...

Comment: Also, I just realized, you need to use `window.getComputedStyle(...)` to get the current actual value of those properties. The `.style.` only contains the value defined in the CSS...

Comment: it seems like elements are not made for stuff that I want to do here. I should go with canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about the units!

I changed your snippet to keep the actual values in 2 variables and added a function to update the circles style properties by using those vars and appending the units.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML Test</title>
        <style>
            #circle {
                width: 50px;
                height: 50px;
                border-radius: 25px;
                background: red;
                position: absolute;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="circle"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
        var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
        var circleLeft = 0;
        var circleTop = 0;
        
        var updatePosition = function(left, top) {
           circle.style.left = left + 'px';
           circle.style.top = top + 'px';
        };

        // once at the start
        updatePosition(circleLeft, circleTop);
        
        document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                circleLeft += 100;
                console.log("right");
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                circleTop += 100;
                console.log("bottom");
            }
            updatePosition(circleLeft, circleTop);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing this, but as
Rene said in the comments, you are dealing with strings not numbers and therefore will have trouble actually preforming simple operations like += 100. You instead need to substring the style string, parse the number from it and then add your number, then re-add the "px" to the end (actually might not be necessary since it seems to infer that 100 == 100px in HTML, but not the other way around.)

Here is a fix that worked for moving it left!

```
    <script>
        circle.style.left = "0px";
        document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
        
            if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                
                console.log(circle.style.left.substring(0,circle.style.left.length -2))
                circle.style.left = (parseInt(circle.style.left.substring(0,circle.style.left.length -2)) + 100) + "px"
                console.log(circle.style.left)
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                circle.style.top += 100;
                console.log("bottom")
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working example. I have set the 10px move position instead of 100px.

Here you can move the circle infinite times as well instead of the single move.

```js
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
            var circle = document.getElementById("circle");

            if (event.keyCode == 39) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    (i => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            const left = window.getComputedStyle(circle).left;
                            circle.style.left = `${(+left.replace("px", "") + i * 2) %
                            window.innerWidth}px`;
                        }, 500);
                    })(i);
                }
            } else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
                for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                    (i => {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            const top = window.getComputedStyle(circle).top;
                            circle.style.top = `${(+top.replace("px", "") + j * 2) %
                            window.innerWidth}px`;
                        }, 500);
                    })(j);
                }
            }
        }
```

```css
#circle {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border-radius: 25px;
            background: red;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```